# Can I get the system home directory in CMake on Linux?

Tags: linux, cmake

Is there a variable related to the home_dir(like /home/user) of Linux system in CMake. Or some other easy ways to get it.

Comment: See [CMake may access environment variables.](https://cmake.org/Wiki/CMake/Language_Syntax#CMake_may_access_environment_variables.)

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Home directory is referred to by the `HOME` environment variable, so you can access it in CMake script by:

```
$ENV{HOME}
```

Comment: Nope. This fails in PowerShell.

Answer (score 1):

OP's question is for Linux but for those on Windows, you can get it this way :

```
set(USER_HOME_DIRECTORY $ENV{USERPROFILE})
message(STATUS "User Home Directory: ${USER_HOME_DIRECTORY}")
```