# cmake wrapping command with unwanted quotes inside add_custom_command

Tags: cmake

Using cmake 2.8.12.1, I have the following lines:

```
set(LCOV ~/tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/check/root/usr/local/bin/lcov)
separate_arguments(LCOV_PARAMS UNIX_COMMAND "--capture --directory ./CMakeFiles/mylib.dir --output-file coverage.info")
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT coverage.info
    COMMAND ${LCOV} ${LCOV_PARAMS}
    DEPENDS tests)
```

When I run make with VERBOSE=1, I can see that the command is getting wrapped with double quotes, and of course the shell says "No such file or directory":

```
[100%] Generating coverage.info
"~/tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/check/root/usr/local/bin/lcov" --capture --directory ./CMakeFiles/mylib.dir --output-file coverage.info
/bin/sh: ~/tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/check/root/usr/local/bin/lcov: No such file or directory
```

When I remove *only* the tilde from the command, cmake decides that it doesn't need to double quote it anymore.  The new lines in CMakeLists.txt:

```
#set(LCOV ${JENKINS_TOOL_DIR}/check/root/usr/local/bin/lcov)
set(LCOV /tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/check/root/usr/local/bin/lcov)
separate_arguments(LCOV_PARAMS UNIX_COMMAND "--capture --directory ./CMakeFiles/mylib.dir --output-file coverage.info")
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT coverage.info
    COMMAND ${LCOV} ${LCOV_PARAMS}
    DEPENDS tests)
```

And the resulting run with VERBOSE=1:

```
[100%] Generating coverage.info
/tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/check/root/usr/local/bin/lcov --capture --directory ./CMakeFiles/mylib.dir --output-file coverage.info
make[3]: /tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/check/root/usr/local/bin/lcov: Command not found
```

I can't figure out why cmake is deciding to add quotes for me.  I've tried VERBOSE.  I've tried putting the command string into add_custom_command (avoiding the set() call).  As long as the tilde is there, cmake is smarter, and surrounds my entire command with unwanted double quotes.

How can I execute my command including the tilde without having the string quoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I've posted the question I found a solution.

[The tilde can be replaced with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32866503/can-i-get-the-system-home-directory-in-cmake-on-linux) `$ENV{HOME}`.

So my command becomes:

```
set(LCOV $ENV{HOME}/tools/com.cloudbees.jenkins.plugins.customtools.CustomTool/check/root/usr/local/bin/lcov)
```

This solved the problem for me.